# Adding jquery dragdrop to knockout

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sortable and droppable knockout list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273818/sortable-and-droppable-knockout-list)

I am using knockout to bind a UL. I am wanting to gives users the ability to drag and drop a LI and for my viewmodel to update with the reorder.

Drag and drop is working and I have the correct event working within my jquery but I am not sure how to make the update.

I have had a hunt around the documentation but cant find anything.

I've created a fiddle to make explaining what I am doing a little easier

[Js Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/RS2VM/1/)

Any suggestions would be awesome!

Updated the jsfiddle link

Comment: Something in that fiddle is supposed to be dragable?

Comment: hey @JMM yes your right. I have fixed the link

Comment: Just FYI ... you can rewrite the toJSON like this (new on Knockout 2.1) self.lastSavedJson(ko.toJSON(self.questions, null, 2));

Comment: This plugin might help you too: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never worked with Knockout and I don't have time to understand its intricacies right now, so this isn't a complete solution, but [here's something to get you started](http://jsfiddle.net/RS2VM/2/).  See below for links to some pages I found while searching that may help you complete the solution.

This is the part that I changed from your [original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spnz/RS2VM/1/):

```
var view_model = new ViewModel(initialData);

ko.applyBindings(view_model);

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        stop: function(event, ui) { console.log("stop event")},


        start : function ( event, ui ) {

            ui.item.data( 'previous_index', ui.item.index() );

        },
        // start


        update : function ( event, ui ) {

            var question = view_model.questions.splice(

              ui.item.data( 'previous_index' ), 1

            )[0];

            view_model.questions.splice( ui.item.index(), 0, question );

            ui.item.removeData( 'previous_index' );

        }
        // update

    });
});
```

References:

[jQuery UI Sortable, how to determine current location and new location in update event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601827/jquery-ui-sortable-how-to-determine-current-location-and-new-location-in-update)

[get the start position of an item using the jquery ui sortable plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620601/get-the-start-position-of-an-item-using-the-jquery-ui-sortable-plugin)

[jQuery Sortable() with original position placeholder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209029/jquery-sortable-with-original-position-placeholder)

[knockout + jqueryui draggable/droppable follow-up](http://wilsonhut.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/knockout-jquery-ui-draggabledroppable-follow-up/)

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Niemeyer has authored a Knockout plug-in for this purpose:

- https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Here is an updated blog entry:

- http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html